# Distinct and return one value from where clause

Tags: sql-server, distinct

Before i write down here, i've spend whole day to solve this query. Please help me to fix this.

```
table source:
      ID | FID | ROLE
       1 | 1 |  16
       2 | 1 |  17
       3 | 1 |  16
       4 | 2 |  16
       5 | 2 |  17
       6 | 2 |  16


result:
  ID | FID | ROLE
   3 | 1 |  16
   6 | 2 |  16
```

Databse: SQL SERVER
Description: The result that i need is distinct the FID value (return single value/single row) but only for role=16 and pick the greater/largest ID.

Thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way to do it.

```
select 
  max(id) as id, 
  fid, 
  role 
from source 
where role = 16
group by
  fid, 
  role
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, FID, ROLE
FROM Table_Name
WHERE ROLE = 16
GROUP BY FID, ROLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct FID, max(ID)
from Tabel_Name
group by FID
```